# PHP MySQL read data as a row

Tags: php, mysql

Bit confused here, for example I have user table like this:

```
--------------------------------
|  id  | name  | pass  | email |
--------------------------------
|   1  | a     | a     | a@a.a |
--------------------------------
|   2  | b     | b     | b@b.b |
--------------------------------
|   3  | c     | c     | c@c.c |
--------------------------------
```

I can use this command

```
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM user");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $username = $row['name'];
    $password = $row['pass'];
```

But get problem when I have this options table like this

```
------------------------------
|  id  | name      | content |
------------------------------
|   1  | username  | a       |
------------------------------
|   2  | password  | a       |
------------------------------
|   3  | email     | a@a.a   |
------------------------------
|   4  | url       | a.com   |
------------------------------
```

How  can I query this table? the point is I want to create options table but not adding data to right, but to bottom so the point "name value = content value"

```
    username = a;
    password = a;
    email = a@a.a;
    url = a.com;
```

I really don't know how to explain it, this is new for me

Comment: What is the identifier used in the table 2

Comment: actually i want to create mysql table like wp_options like this http://prntscr.com/4nyfeq similar function but not for wp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can experiment with [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) in PHP. So for instance, in your example above, try something like this:

```
$username = '';

// query your OPTIONS table here
// assuming you've called it 'user' as described in your question
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM user");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    // note the extra $ prefix before $row['name']
    // this creates the variable from the contents of $row['name']
    $$row['name'] = $row['content'];
}

echo $username; // should return 'a'
```

In a nutshell, the "name" column of your row holds the variable name and the "content" column holds the value.

Answer (score 0):

Your options table is a common abstraction used in relational database systems called Entity-Attribute-Value. Here is a cute write-up:

http://mikesmithers.wordpress.com/2013/12/22/the-anti-pattern-eavil-database-design

Here's how you'd query your `options` table:

```
<?php
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM options");
?>
```

Here's how you'd capture the information to a PHP array:

```
<?php
$user = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $user[ $row['name'] ] = $row['content'];
}
var_dump( $user );
?>
```

Here is how you might access the data:

```
<html>
<p>username: <?= $user['username'] ?></p>
<p>password: <?= $user['password'] ?></p>
</html>
```

Note that you probably need to add a `user_id` column to your options table. That's how your EAV table will be able to support multiple users.